# NetBeans 8.2 C++ debugger skips all breakpoints

Tags: c++, netbeans, gdb

I have been using NetBeans C++ (8.2) and I have been happy with it until today.  I include a *.h file and work with it.  When trying to debug, it skips all breakpoints and goes all the way to the end.

I decide to comment out the current main(), and re-use main() from the previous project (which uses other *.h files), and it skips properly.  I revert to the current main() and get skipped all to way to the end again.

I then decide to put the debug code at the top of the old main(), and now it enters from the beginning and wait for my stepping command.

I am at a loss right now.  Can someone tell me what is going on?  I cannot think of a possible explanation.  I do not know how to use gdb by the way.

---

I can also add another line that calls the other *.h file to create an object, and then the debug works properly again.  What am I experiencing?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations?

Comment: I don't know.  How can I check?

Comment: OK, under Build >> C++ Compiler >> Debug, Release - Additional Options >> All Options: -g -std=c++11.